# undefined reference to `explain_read' ...... No such file or directory

Tags: c, hyperlink, reference, compilation, g++

I need to include `libexplain` to my project to do certain job. I install it and add the header `libexplain/read.h` to my code, so far so good and no error reported by the complier. But when I use the function `explain_read()` provided by `libexplain` and build the project it says:

```
/tmp/cc7NjAw0.o: In function `xl45_read(int, unsigned char*)':
connections.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `explain_read'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and the build script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo > ./stdafx.h
g++ -O1 -Wall -o ./local_proxy (*.cpp...here is the source file list) -lz -lpthread -lpcap -L/usr/local/lib
```

actually when I type

```
whereis libexplain
```

in terminal, I get

```
libexplain: /usr/lib/libexplain.so /usr/lib/libexplain.a /usr/include/libexplain
```

I do a lot of searches and still have no idea what's going wrong. ):

Comment: Try adding "-lexplain " to the end of your "g++" line in your build script.

Comment: thank you my friend, problem solved @TonyB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link your object files with `libexplain`. You can do it using the `-l<library name>`, like so:

```
g++ -O1 -Wall -o ./local_proxy *.cpp -lz -lpthread -lpcap -lexplain -L/usr/local/lib
```

Note the `-lexplain` flag. For a library with the a file name like `libABC.so`, you'd use `-lABC` to refer to that library. The [documentation for link options with GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) can shed more light on it.

Comment: build success and thanks so much!! costs me so much time though it's a stupid question... btw how do i know the link parameter for certain library, say it's    `-lexplain` for `libexplain`, how do you find out that...

Comment: There, gave a generic example and a link to the GCC docs. Basically it's got to do with the actual name of the dynamic library you're trying to link against.